# Multiple forms in while loop with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I have a product page whos products are created dynamically from mysql along with "add to cart" buttons and quantity inputs on each item. These items are submitted via AJAX. I'm able to submit the correct product but the success message returned from ajax uses a hidden div which hides the add to cart button then displays text that your item in now in the cart. It hides ALL of the cart button and shows the hidden div containing the success message in every form. Any help to solve this is appreciated!

My PHP/HTML

```
//inside while loop
     ?>
     <div class="form">     
<form action="cart_action.php" method="post" name="form" id="form_<?php echo $item_no; ?>">
     <input type="hidden" class="text" name="order_code" value="<?php echo $item_no; ?>" id="order_code<?php echo $item_no; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" class="text" name="minorder" value="<?php echo $min; ?>" id="min_<?php echo $item_no; ?>" />
<br><br><div style="float:left; padding:5px;"><b>Qty</b>: <input class="text" type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $min; ?>" size="3" id="quan_<?php echo $item_no; ?>" ?></div>
<div id="status"></div>

<input type="image" src="images/add_to_cart.png" class="psubmit" alt="submit" name="submit" id="submit_<?php echo $item_no; ?>" />
 </div><div class="added"><b><div style="color: rgb(85, 176, 90);"><br /><b>Added to Cart </b>(<a href="cart.php" class="gen">View Cart</a>)</div></b></div>          
</form>
    <?php    
    } //end loop
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('form').submit(function(){    
// Catching the DOM element which trigger the event 
var $form = $(this);

            var orderCode = $form.find('input[name=order_code]');
    var quantity = $form.find('input[name=quantity]');
    var minOrder = $form.find('input[name=minorder]');



   if (quantity.val() == '') {
   quantity.addClass('hightlight');
   $form.find("#status").html('<font color="red">Please Enter A Quantity!</font>');
   return false;
} else quantity.removeClass('hightlight');

if (quantity.val() % minOrder.val()) {
quantity.addClass('hightlight');
$form.find("#status").html('<font color="red">Invalid Multiple!</font>');
return false;
} else quantity.removeClass('hightlight');


//organize the data properly
var data = 'order_code=' + orderCode.val() + '&quantity=' + quantity.val();

//disabled all the text fields
//$('.text').attr('disabled','true');

//show the loading sign
$('.loading').show();

//start the ajax
$.ajax({

//this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
url: "cart_action.php", 

//GET method is used
type: "GET",

//pass the data         
data: data,     

//Do not cache the page
cache: false,

//success
success: function (html) {              
//if process.php returned 1/true (send mail success)
if (html==1) {                  
//hide the form
                    $('.form').fadeOut('slow');                 

//show the success message
$('.added').fadeIn('slow');

//if process.php returned 0/false (send mail failed)
} else 
//hide the form
                 $('.form').fadeOut('slow');                    

//show the success message
                $('.added').fadeIn('slow');             
}       
});

//cancel the submit button default behaviours
return false;
e.preventDefault();
});
```

});

Comment: You are using the class selector. `.className`. This will hide all of the elements with that class. Instead you should use  an id selector to select a specific one, or specify the index of the element.

Comment: I see that, and I tried to change it to id selector with # and changing my css.. this works for quantity validation but not for the success message show/hide part.

Comment: I got the `show()` part to work by changing it back to an id sselector and using `$form.find` I also had to move the div around in my html to get i† orking. seems I was closing the form container before this hidden div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your success handler, change the selectors to start from `$form`:

```
$form.fadeOut('slow');

$form.children('.added').fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: This works for all element now by changing the elector a you suggested. it worked on on some element but not all, it was because I had some outside the form div in my html. Thanks!